# Sync failed when I have 2steps verification

Tags: sync, 2-step-verification

I do on phone factory reset and after that I can't sync when I have turned on 2steps verification but when I turn off verification all works correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: re-generate the application specific password for your device and use that randomly generated password for your google a/c sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it is Google Authenticator? If So, Please refer it might be worked.

Please verify your time on smartphone is correct and do re-setup 2FA or re-generate ASP again it might be worked. Some user in Japan has similar problem.

Google Authenticator require having correct time between your phone and Google Account server. Also each node such your smartphone has NTP client and use different NTP server depends on maker.

(I would like to put this as comment but I have no rights yet.)

Comment: When I just using phone. I can't sync Gmail, Hangout and Contacts. But when I turn off 2-step-verification all works :/ I create second gmail account to check but still don't work...

Comment: @Kris Groove It seems be Google is working on this currently according to [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum) of Japan

Comment: please try to clear the cache and remove your account once and add your account as you did before.